# get stdin for other pane in tmux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, console, tmux

How could I have stdin from another panel in tmux ?,
I have this test script (test_script):

```
echo "tell me something: "
read var
echo "said $var"
```

I send the script to be executed in panel 2:

```
tmux run-shell -t 2 'sh test_script'
```

but in panel 2 I get just this:

```
tell me something: 
said
```

panel 2 skips stdin and I need to have stdin in panel 2 but I see that it does not work, how could I solve this?

also try with pipe:

```
tmux pipe-pane -o -t 2 'sh test_script > /dev/pts/12'
```

but I get the following:

```
tell me something: 
hallo
No command 'hallo' found, did you mean:
Command 'hello' from package 'hello' (main)
Command 'hello' from package 'hello-traditional' (universe)
hallo: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

run-shell -t only controls where the output is displayed. pipe-pane will send any output from the pane not anything you type into the pane.

You need to run your script actually in the pane, which means replacing what it is in there already. Use respawn-pane, or split-window if you prefer a new pane.

Comment: So, is it possible to execute interactive shell or binary in tmux run-shell or any tmux command else?